# Density plot and histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have the following data frame

```
        x1<-data.frame(n = rnorm(1000000, mean=0, sd=1), nombre= "x1")

        x2<-data.frame(n=rnorm(1500000, mean=3, sd=1), nombre= "x2")

        x<-rbind(x1, x2)

        ggplot(x, aes(n, fill=nombre))+
          geom_histogram(alpha=0.5, binwidth=0.25, position = "identity")+
          geom_density()
```

I would like to overlay the density plot to the histogram, but it just appears like a thin line in 0

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to get `geom_histogram` and `geom_density` to share the same axis.  In this case, I've specified both to plot against density by adding the `aes(y=..density)` term to `geom_histogram`.  Note also some different aesthetics to avoid overplotting and so that we are able to see both geoms a bit more clearly:

```
ggplot(x, aes(n, fill=nombre))+
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), color='gray50',
        alpha=0.2, binwidth=0.25, position = "identity")+
    geom_density(alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

As initially specified, the aesthetics `fill=` applies to both, so you have the histogram and density geoms showing you distribution grouped according to "x1" and "x2".  If you want the density geom for the combined set of x1 and x2, just specify the `fill=` aesthetic for the histogram geom only:

```
ggplot(x, aes(n))+
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill=nombre),
        color='gray50', alpha=0.2,
        binwidth=0.25, position = "identity")+
    geom_density(alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: But I would like the density of the whole distribution, not grouped

Comment: Use `geom_density(alpha=0)` for a better view.

Comment: @AdriánVallsCarbó - see the adjustment in the answer.  You should specify the `fill=` aesthetic within the specific geom.  In the example, I've moved it so that the histogram geom is showing distributions for x1 and x2, whereas the density geom shows for the whole distribution of x.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with an idea that allow you to scale your density plot according to your histogram.

You can get density data using `stat:density` function and scale them manually, then plot them using `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(x, aes(n, fill=nombre))+
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.5, binwidth=0.25, position = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x,y, group=nombre),
    ~ .x %>% group_by(nombre) %>%
      mutate(n_cut = cut(n, seq(min(n), max(n), 0.25))) %>% 
      summarize(
        y = density(n)$y * max(table(n_cut)) / max(density(n)$y),
        x = density(n)$x
      )
  )
```

[image: result]