# How do you plot density curves on top of the data to show distribution in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution, density-plot

I am looking to plot the density curves within the distribution of my data. I have heard (not not expert) on something called lognormal distribution?
My data is the following:

```
data<- data.frame(
      Day=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
      Variable=c(3,5,20,10,8,18,23,21,16,12))

ggplot(data)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=Variable, x=Day),stat="identity", colour="black")+
  labs(title= "",x="",y=expression('Variable'))+  theme_classic()
```

[image]

And would like something like this:
[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you first need to fit a gaussian mixture model to data using packages like `mclust`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Density plot and histogram in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548507/density-plot-and-histogram-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming here that your data are frequencies, therefore in order to
simplify subsequent operations, first transform them into a vector of single observations.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


long <- with(data, rep(Day, times = Variable))

long[1:20]

[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Now using `ggplot` you can plot the histogram and density estimate:

```r
data.frame(Day = long) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Day), stat = "count") +
  geom_density(aes(x = Day, after_stat(count)))
```

[image: UNIMODAL DENSITY]

To fit a mixture of two gaussian distributions (as in the reference example), you can use `mclust`. Note that this is shown only as an example and it is probably not the best way to treat your data. Here, the parameter `G` specifies the number of models:

```r
library(mclust)
fit <- densityMclust(long, G = 2)
```

Next, the data are prepared for plotting using ggplot in several steps:

- the density estimates are produced for both gaussian models in a suitable range of `x` using `predict`
- the density values are scaled to match the proportion of observations predicted to be in either model
- the dataframe is rearranged pivoting on the `x`

```r
x <- seq(0, max(long) + 1, by = 0.1)

dens <- predict(fit, x, what = "cdens") |>
  apply(1, function(z) z*table(fit$classification)) |>
  t() |>
  data.frame() |>
  cbind(x = x) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = c(X1, X2),
               names_to = "K",
               values_to = "y")
```

Finally, the densities are layered upon the barplot, by specifying in `geom_line` that the source of data is `dens`:

```r
data.frame(Day = long) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Day), stat = "count") +
  geom_line(data = dens,
            aes(x = x, y = y, color = K))
```

[image: BIMODAL DENSITY]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're getting a bit confused between a bar chart and a histogram. You have a *bar chart*, which in your case is showing the change in one variable on the y axis against time on the x axis.

A histogram looks like a bar chart, but it shows the distribution of a *single variable* throughout its range. This has the value of the variable on the x axis, and the frequency with which that variable was found on the y axis. It makes sense to plot a density curve over a histogram, but not over a time series. If you are looking for a similar visual effect to the plot shown, the best you can get is probably to plot a moving average along with the bars, perhaps something like this:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(Day, Variable))  + 
  geom_col(colour = "black") +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, color = "black") +
  labs(title = "", x = "", y = expression('Variable')) +  
  theme_classic()
```

[image]